# Will the real unique index please stand up?

Tags: db2, indexing, unique-constraint, unique-index

I recently encountered a DB2 table that has three different indexes that are unique.

```
Index 1 (Columns: A, B, C)
Index 2 (Columns: A, B, C, D)
Index 3 (Columns: A, B, C, D, E)
```

Is the most specific one the *actual* unique index? Or does the definition of uniqueness differ depending about which index DB2 uses to access the table?

I'm a bit confused since, index 1 suggests that as long as my values for A, B, C are unique, I can have duplicate values for D and E. But then there's index 3 saying that A, B, C, D, E are unique, so I can't have duplicate values for D and E after all?

Comment: if (A, B, C) is unique, so is any superset of columns (easy to prove by contradiction)

Comment: So (A, B, C, D, E) is unique + extra? Not necessarily all that necessary for uniqueness?

Comment: Yes, that's what the existence of those unique indexes would indicate.

Comment: @Bwmat If you'd like to post an answer, have a go at it, otherwise I'll post one sometime.

Comment: What "flavor" of DB2? DB2 for i allows the three to be totally separate or physically a single index. It can depend on (1) attributes at creation time and (2) the order they were created.

Comment: @user2338816, unfortunately I don't really know. I'm not the DBA at my company.

Comment: Index1 and index2 aren't necessary.  Index3 would handle all of the queries based on index1 or index2.  I suspect index1 was the original unique index.  Index2 was created later for a particular query,  Index3 was created later for another particular query.  Index3 gives a slight performance gain over index1 and index2 when the query can be satisfied by the columns in the index.

Answer (score 1):

Quite the opposite, the only unique index that counts is Index 1 (for uniqueness).

I haven't tried it, but for accessing purpose, DB2 would use the index that is better for the actual query you are performing.

For instance, if you are querying { A=1, B=2, C=3 } it should use Index 1;
if you are querying {A =1, B=2, C=3, D=4 } it should use Index 2, even if it could just use Index 1, but you won't see any performance gain.

Comment: Index2 gives a slight performance gain over index1 if the query can be satisfied by the columns in the index.

Comment: In theory: yes. In reality, for this specific case Index2 is really not more efficient, since they both point to the same record in a atomic operation, the check to D is useless. As I said I haven't tried it and I'd like to be proved wrong, but I don't thinkg you would gain 1 s in any query because of Index2.